# Use GameScene in another class

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I try to use addChild in a self created class:

```
self.addChild(chip)
```

Error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'SKSpriteNode' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'
```

Then I came to the conclusion that I couldn't use `self`. Therefore I try the following example:

```
Battlefield.addChild(chip)
```

Battlefield is the name of the class, but also here is an error:

```
'SKSpriteNode' is not convertible to 'Battlefield'
```

This would work in the GameScene class, but how can I do it in the Battlefield class?

I would be very grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows what is going wrong.
I guess "chip" is a SpriteKite Node ('SKSpriteNode'). You have to add it to a SpriteKitScene or another SpriteKit Node.

For example something like

```
self.myScene.addChild(chip)
```